# Spy++ Win32 API Getting Window instance from Spy++ Information

Tags: c++, winapi, spy++

I am using Spy++ to find windows, I am doing this as a test and realise the Handles change fequently. However, here is the information I get from Spy++. Can I use these handles to grab that window in C++

Here's how I get it from the name.

`HWND main_window_handle = FindWindowA(NULL, WINDOW_NAME);`

How can I get it using either the Window Handle or Instance Handle.
[image]

Comment: The "Window Handle" (aka `HWND`) is what you are trying to find.  You can't convert a module "Instance Handle" (aka `HINSTANCE`) to a "Window Handle" (but you can enumerate windows and check if they belong to a specific "Instance Handle").  From the screenshot, the "Window Caption" is blank, so all you really have to search by is the "Class Name" (look at the "Class" tab), which you would pass in the `lpszClass` parameter of `FindWindow/Ex()`.  Be careful if there are multiple instances of the window's Class Name active on your system. You will have to figure out a way to differentiate them.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish exactly? Maybe a [mcve] of what you want to do with the `HWND` once you find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The window handle **is** the `HWND` and their values are not stable, it will probably change every time you run the program.
- The instance handle (`HINSTANCE`) is also not stable and has little to do with finding a specific window in another application, it is the load address of the module (.exe or .dll) that created the window.

To find a window you will generally call [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx) with a specific class name. If the class name of the window you are looking for is not really unique then you should probably use [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) and try to look for other specific attributes and/or child windows to identify the top level window you are looking for.

It is also possible (and often the best approach) to use [UI Automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation) to find and manipulate windows in 3rd-party applications.

Comment: Actually, there's a pretty intimate relationship between window classes and modules. The class name and the module registering that class uniquely identify a window class. See [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873) for the full story.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
HINSTANCE myInstance = (HINSTANCE)&__ImageBase;
```